# How to run randomForest efficiently without cluster

Tags: r, performance, lapply, random-forest

I have several randomForest models which have same independent variables(X), different dependent variable(Y). Is there any way to run these model efficiently without cluster? Currently I use lapply to run them sequentially.

```
library(randomForest)
data(iris)

iris_new<-iris[,c(1:ncol(iris),rep(ncol(iris),4))]

tt<-lapply(1:5, function (i){
iris.rf <- randomForest(as.formula(paste(colnames(iris_new)[4+i],'.',sep='~')), data=iris_new,  importance=TRUE)
iris.pred <- predict(iris.rf, iris_new[i,])  

})
```

In the example above, there are 5 randomforest models. the first four columns are the independent variables for different models. The last 5 columns are the dependent variables for each model.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution can be to use dopar from the parallel package. It will allow you to use all your cores to grow the trees. If you have four cores you can use each of them to grow a tree each and then combine them using combine function of the package.